# how to rename a number of files using wildcard as prefix

Tags: linux, bash, files, rename

Assume I have many files names something like:

```
foo_192.168.1.1.sh
bar_192.168.1.1.sh
baz_192.168.1.1.sh
qux_192.168.1.1.sh
```

and I want to rename them all to

```
foo_192.168.1.100.sh
bar_192.168.1.100.sh
baz_192.168.1.100.sh
qux_192.168.1.100.sh
```

How would I do this best?

`mv *.1.sh .100.sh` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably 1000 ways to do this. Here's the first that came to mind:

```
rename 's/1\.sh/100.sh/' *
```

`rename` takes a  pattern as the first argument and attempts to rename the target files.